# Simple two cells check and calculate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have problems with this formula and cant get it right.
I cant use the "IFS" in my excel.

Want I would like to calculate for Cell C1:

```
If A1 is empty and B1 is empty = 0
If A1 is not empty and B1 is empty = A1
If A1 is empty and B1 is not empty = B1
If A1 is not empty and B1 is not empty = (A1*0,6) + (B1*0,4)
```

Example for last

```
A1 = 20 and B1 = 2

= (A1*0,6) + (B1*0,4) 
= 20 *0,6 + 2*0,4 
= 12 + 0,8 
= 12,8
```

Thank you

Comment: this part is hard to understand: `A1*0,6 + B2*0,4` if a1 = 1 and b2 = 1 what would the output be?

Comment: The output would be (1 * 0,6) + (1 *0,4) = 0,6 + 0,4 = 1

Comment: ahh, sorry, I use `.` not `,` for decimal.  makes sense.

Comment: This should work, try 
`=IFS(AND(A1="",B2=""),0,AND(A1<>"",B2=""),A1,AND(A1="",B2<>""),B2,AND(A1<>"",B2<>""),(A1*0.6)+(B2*0.4))`

Comment: My Excel dont offer the "IFS" only "IF"

Comment: Ok, then use IF inplace of IFS, `=IF(AND(A1="",B2=""),0,IF(AND(A1<>"",B2=""),A1,IF(AND(A1="",B2<>""),B2,IF(AND(A1<>"",B2<>""),(A1*0.6)+(B2*0.4)))))`

Comment: Try: `=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>""),A1*0.6+B1*0.4,A1+B1)`

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya
thank you! it works like a champ :)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad dont work for example if B1 is empty I get an error

Comment: No use the one shared by @cybernetic.nomad sir, that is easy

Comment: @Rayzo1 the one shared by cybernetic.nomad sir, also works there is no doubt in it, and i am sure the cell B1 seems empty to naked eyes might be there is some offending non printable characters or may be a space